# simple present instead of simple past

Tags: grammar

I heard this sentence in "The Vicar of Dibley"(S01E01):

> *He **come** second in the marrow-growing contest in 1956.*

Why does he use simple present instead of simple past?

Comment: Because that's *normal* in casual/uneducated speech. We're quite prepared to mix the two even in a single sentence: [*So I **give** him a slap on the ear and **left** before his ma found out why he was bawling.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22So+I+give+him+a+slap+on+the+ear+and+left+before+his+ma+found+out+why+he+was+bawling.%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (but don't ask me to explain why it would be completely non-idiomatic to reverse those two with ***gave*** and ***leave***, 'cos that's *way* beyond my pay grade! :)

Comment: Also note that your example (not uncommon) isn't even "correct" present tense (that would be *He **comes** second*, which does also occur in similar contexts). I'd hesitate to call the cited example an unmarked infinitive, but perhaps it is.

Comment: @Fumble: I would hesitate to use the word 'uneducated'. It's just a dialectal version of speech. Vicar of Dibley being set in rural Oxfordshire. Identity has more to do with it more than education.

Comment: @Jascol: Oh, come on! I can't call all the characters to mind off the top of my head, but apart from Dawn French's vicar, I think they're practically all "locals". As it happens, all the characters likely to have uttered the cited text here are exaggeratedly dumb/uneducated, rather than "authentically rustic". But I use these forms myself quite freely in appropriate conversational contexts, and I'm not a dialectal speaker, nor am I dumb or uneducated.

Comment: I don't think this is historic present, @FumbleFingers (which is what your example is), First, it doesn't feel like narration, and secondly, as you point out, if it were historic present it would be _comes_. I think it's purely dialect

Comment: @Colin: Curiously, I find that if I I really try to envisage "dialectal historic present narration" for my example, I find myself drawn to *So I **gives** him a slap on the ear and **leaves** before his ma **finds** out why he's [he **is**] bawling.* Either that, or the vowel sound in the "target" word ***gave*** reduces to /ɛ/ - similar to how *ate* past tense of *eat* can be /eɪt/ or /ɛt/. (Assuming I've got those symbols right, which is a somewhat optimistic assumption! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a dialect variant. It is still past, not present.

Comment: For confirmation, the OED has, under past tense forms of the verb *come*, "*mod. dial.* coome, come."